# AWS Lambda Function (Python) - How to use external libraries?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a Lambda function (Python) with the code below:

```
import json
import qrcode
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    input_data = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81xuW7h1tkL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            box_size=10,
            border=5)
    qr.add_data(input_data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
    file_name = "qrcode001.png"
    img.save(file_name)
    string = "WhatAmIGoodFor"
    encoded_string = string.encode("utf-8")
    bucket_name = "mys3bucket"
    s3_path = "qrcode/" + file_name
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=encoded_string)

    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I installed all modules need in the same folder as below:

[image]

And created it via CLI as below:

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name generate_ticket \
--zip-file fileb://Archive.zip --handler lambda_function.lambda_handler --runtime python3.9 \
--role arn:aws:iam::999999999:role/service-role/generate_ticket-role-hj1kcybi
```

[image]

How can I correctly use external libraries in my Lambda function?

Comment: In the context of Python "lambda" has a [different meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) than in the context am AWS. You should make your context more clear!

Comment: Do you mean the title? I have updated it anyways :-)

Comment: Kaguei for you Klaus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python modules should not be in a folder. They should be at the same level as `lambda_function.py` and then you zip them all together.

If you don't have many dependencies, this is ok, but with more additional libraries, your cold start of lambda function will be slower, so it's preferable to create a lambda layer that will contain your dependencies and attach that layer to the lambda function. For configuration of layers, you can see details in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)